# How to Align Two Array Index's?

Tags: c#

I have an object with one properties of type DateTime[] and one with decimal[], the length of these arrays will be same and each index value corresponds with other array index values.

I would like to get the decimal[] based on filtering of DateTime[], what would be the best way to do this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you explain what filtering you're talking about? If you know the index of the DateTime element, why can't you just use that same index for the decimal index?

Comment: If those `DateTime` and `decimal` values are related you should think about placing them in single `class` and have one `array` instead of 2.

Comment: "Best way" is probably have a single array of a custom Class that contains a DateTime and  decimal.

Comment: What does filtering mean to you? If you iterate over that stuff with a for loop, testing every date against some condition, you automatically know the index of corresponding decimal.

Comment: Also, "indices," or if you must, "indexes"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You, probably, are looking for `Zip`:

```
  DateTime[] dates = ...
  decimal[] decimals = ...

  var result = dates
    .Zip(decimals, (date, dec) => new {
           date = date,
           value = dec
         })
    .Where(item => ...) // The required filter here, e.g. item.date.Year == 2016
    .Select(item => item.value);
```

**Edit**: in case array `index` is required (see comments below), one can add it into `Where`:

```
    ...
    .Where((item, index) => ...) // Put filter, e.g. item.date.Year == 2016 || index > 3
    ...
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was looking for. Thanks. Is there a way to get the index number also inside the Zip func?

Comment: @Deepak: in case you want array `index` as well as date, just use `index` in `Where` (see my edit)

Comment: Dmitry Bychenko one query, the Where condition in your example, will it run after the Zip or before?

Comment: @Deepak: *after*, as in the example above; the only change is in the `Where` format

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use `List` but if you really want to stick to Arrays:

```
DateTime[] dateArray = new DateTime[10];
decimal[] decArray = new decimal[10];

DateTime someDate = new DateTime(1999, 10, 23);

decimal item_from_array = decArray[dateArray.ToList().IndexOf(someDate)];
```

if you need a filter you can use the `Find` method:

```
decimal item_from_array_filter = decArray[dateArray.ToList().IndexOf(dateArray.ToList().Find(x=>x.Year == 1999))];
```

Version 2 if you would use a list.

```
List<DateTime> dateList = new List<DateTime>();
decimal item = decArray[dateList.IndexOf(someDate)];
```